# Receiving empty error response in apache camel api

Tags: spring, exception, apache-camel

I am new to Apache Camel. My requirement is that, whenever a custom exception occur, i want to set a custom Body and response code and send it back to the user as response.
I have used OnException Block to catch the custom exception :

```
onException(CustomException.class)
                .handled(true)
                .to("direct:customErrorHandler");
```

My customErrorHandler is a route in a different class "CustomErrorhandler":-

```
@Component
public class CustomExceptionHandler extends RouteBuilder {
    
    @Autowired
    private CommonExceptionProcessor commonExceptionProcessor;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        JacksonDataFormat jackErrorResponse = new JacksonDataFormat(jacksonConfig.jsonObjectMapper(), Error.class);

        from("direct:customErrorHandler")
                .routeId("customErrorHandler-Route")
                .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, this.getClass().getName(), "Handling Error")
                .process(commonExceptionProcessor)
                .marshal(jackErrorResponse)
           }
}
```

My Common expection processor:-

```
@Component
public class CommonExceptionProcessor implements Processor {
    
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {


       CustomException ex = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, CustomException.class);
        Error e = new Error();
        e.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
        e.setStatus("FAILED");
        exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, ex.getCode());
        exchange.getIn().setBody(e,Error.class);
        }
}
```

But whenever this exception is occuring, i am getting empty response with garbage statusCode. please help.

Expectated Response:

```
{
"message":"customException occured",
"status":"FAILED"
}
```